# Birthday alert webpart in sharepoint 2013

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to create a birthday alert webpart using the out of the box features of SharePoint 2013.

Have anyone tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easy with the content search WebPart.

Configure it to check a birthday field to see if it matches today.

It's so straight forward after you have added it.. I don't think I need to say more.

Comment: Thanks fr the response hugh wood... but i am very new to sharepoint.. can u detail it more further please.. do i need to use calculated column on the list...help s much appreciated

Comment: Not at all. Add the web part and click edit then select "Change query" In here you set the basic list settings, refiners and you have a test window to get the results right in. 2013 makes this sort of operation easy. Note this won't work if your search isn't properly set up.

Comment: can u suggest me ways to show up his profile pic along with the bday wishes

Comment: Return the picture url and format that returned information into an image using a template.

Comment: hi thanks for the response hugh but...one important thing is am asked to implement this in sharepoint 2013 foundation.. where there is no content search WebPart... please suggest me alternatives

Comment: For that you will have to write a webpart that does the same thing. You need to lookup how to make a KQL (Keyword Query Language) request to search.

Comment: cant i acheive this using the oob features without coding much:( ???

Comment: Not on that version of SharePoint no. Sorry.

Comment: so no oob features.. hmm! please help me with solid alternatives... i wil try n follow ur appraoches

Comment: The only real alternative is to have someone who can code it for you if you aren't able. Or perhaps look for one on codeplex. It may have already been written. My email is on my profile if you wish to email me and I can be of more detailed assistance there.

Answer (score 2):

I recently created a web part that does this. It's mostly JavaScript. In short:

1. Create a managed property for the Birthday user profile property
2. Have users edit their profile to include their Birthday
3. Run a full crawl
4. Then use search to filter on the managed property and return results.

You can download and get the code I used here: http://www.lestersconyers.com/javascript-templating-with-sharepoint-2013-part-3/